# D3: Combine two colour scales into one

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I currently have two variables that I can map to two different colours on two colours scales s1 and s2. s1 gives me the shade of red corresponding to my a value of my variable X (4 different possible colours). s1 gives me the shade of blue corresponding to my a value of my variable Y (4 different possible colours too).

Now what I would like to get is something that allows me to combine these two to get a unique colour for a combination of the variables. So for a pair (X,Y) I get a colour on the scale. So I get a scale of 16 possible colours.

Here is a legend that illustrate the kind of thing I am looking for:

[image]

I have been looking at online examples but cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could combine two threshold scales fairly easily into a new scale function. The core of the function could look like:

```
d3.scaleBivariate = function() {
  function scaleBivariate(value) {
    var r = reds(value[0]);
    var b = blues(value[1]);

    return "rgb("+r+","+((r+b)/2)+","+b+")";
  }

  var blues = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);

  var reds = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);

  return scaleBivariate;

}
```

This sets the red and blue channels with the help of two d3 threshold scales. The green is simply set as the average between the two, though you could set that to whatever is desirable, say 0 or the minimum of the two other channels. My red/blue ranges are arbitrary and easily changed as well.

The above could be used as:

```js
d3.scaleBivariate = function() {
  function scaleBivariate(value) {
    var r = reds(value[0]);
    var b = blues(value[1]);

    return "rgb("+r+","+((r+b)/2)+","+b+")";
  }

  var blues = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
        
  var reds = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
        
  return scaleBivariate;

}

// Dummy data:
var data = d3.range(16).map(function(d) {
  return {x: d%4, y: Math.floor(d/4) }
})


var svg = d3.select("svg");
var size = 30;

var color = d3.scaleBivariate();

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x * size })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y * size })
  .attr("width",size)
  .attr("height",size)
  .attr("fill",function(d) {
    return color([d.x,d.y]);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

Of course you might want to add some flexibility by adding methods to modify what datum property sets what colors are associated with what properties, what the thresholds should be, etc. To provide a basic example, the example below has added accessors for setting what property should be mapped to blue and red channels:

```js
d3.scaleBivariate = function() {

  function scaleBivariate(value) {
     var r = reds(red(value));
     var b = blues(blue(value));
     return "rgb("+r+","+((r+b)/2)+","+b+")";
  }
  
  var blues = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
    
  var reds = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([255,205,155,105,55])
    .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
    
  var red = function(d) { return d[0]; }
  
  var blue = function(d) { return d[1];}
  
  // Accessors:
  scaleBivariate.red = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (red = _, scaleBivariate): red;
  }
  
  scaleBivariate.blue = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (blue = _, scaleBivariate): blue;  
  }
  
  return scaleBivariate;
}

var data = d3.range(16).map(function(d) {
  return {x: d%4, y: Math.floor(d/4) }
})

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var size = 30;

// set up the color scale:
var color = d3.scaleBivariate()
  .red(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .blue(function(d) { return d.y; });

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x * size })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y * size })
  .attr("width",size)
  .attr("height",size)
  .attr("fill",color);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Very nice example with good explanations. Definitely deserves a +1. Is this good flexible enough to use something else than just colour? For instance how would you modify it to have one variable mapped to colour and the other to transparency? Or use a predefined scale like interpolateViridis?

Comment: In other words, how would you modify that to be able to use 1°) a transparency scale and two the scales predefined by d3 like interpolateViridis?

Comment: You should be able to use a ramp and opacity, though that might be simpler to just use `.attr("fill"`, and `.attr("opacity"`. To adapt the answer, instead of specifying individual color channels you could specify rgb based on a viridis scale and alpha with the second scale (using d3.rgb to access individual colors) - something like this maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/5Lo1afkw/. To have a single scale object that can do either a ramp/opacity or combination of individually specified color channels would take a bit of work - and a different approach is needed for patterns if using texture with color

Comment: Thanks that totally answers my question. Answer approved. Wish I could upvote again, it's very clear and the code is nice and commented.